# NCurses extra spacing between characters on Windows command prompt

Tags: cmd, ncurses

I just started using the `ncurses` library that came with my MinGW64, `gcc` 5.3.0 on a Windows 7 machine.  With the following code:

```
initscr();
noecho();
raw();
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
printw("Hello there.");
getmaxyx(stdscr, row, col);
printw("\nRow: %3d", row);
printw("\nCol: %3d", col);
printw("\nSomething %c", 0x2605);
refresh();
endwin();
```

I get this as output:

[image]

I've tried changing the font in the command line, which didn't help.  And I can't find anything on Google for why it's doing that.  Changing my linking from `ncursesw` to `ncurses` doesn't help.

What can I do to fix this so that it prints out normally without all of the extra spacing?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a function `print` besides `printw`? It looks like an encoding issue to me...

Comment: Added a picture to show the problem at hand a bit better.  @aschipfl That command is basically Print to Window, so the W so I believe that it's not using wide.  I do agree that it's probably an encoding issue of some kind, just not sure about it yet.

Comment: It's unlikely a fault or misconfigured setting of `cmd.exe`. Does `BVCS.exe` not have configurable options? If not, you're going to have to implement a conversion somehow.

Comment: It's a program I just started writing to learn ncurses.  So, no configuration at this time.

Comment: If you haven't already found it on your searches, take a look at [this Super User question and answers](https://superuser.com/q/269818).

Comment: Changing the code pages does not fix the issue.  `raw()` simply disables input buffering and should not affect output at all.  Even without calling `raw()` it shows the same signs.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest version of MinGW64 resolved the issue for me.  The `gcc` version is 8.1.0.